# Material looks different on object

Tags: rendering, materials

I have been using a procedural material that I go online. I appended the object from the blend model it was supplied in (the SolidModel) and that looks brilliant in rendering, once I ensured the rendering settings were the same.

I have been attempting to use this on a plane outline of a house wall (with a solid modifier) that is in my blend file. That looks 2d rather than 3d. So I added a cube to test whether this would look 3d using the material. It was 2d. So only the original object supplied with the material looks right.

This, I realise, will be a basic misunderstanding I have of how to utilise procedural materials i rendering but I do need help. Can anyone explain what I need to do to ensure I get the 3d effect on my objects?

I have attached pictures of the rendering (couldnt wait until finished but the tiles i am interested in are fully rendered).

A copy of my blend file is at the following address:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmc1zl3ds7xnpwd/canterbury.blend?dl=0

[image: Rendering]

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a subdivision modifier like your other objects in the scene to get the displacement.

Result after subdividing some times:

[image]